# How to access random material in a renderer besides first without cloning any materials except accessed one?

Tags: unity, shaders, rendering, materials

Clones only first material:

```
renderer.material
```

Clones all materials in the same renderer:

```
renderer.materials[0]
```

Comment: Cloning? In what context is this cloning?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-material.html

Modifying material will change the material for this object only.

If the material is used by any other renderers, this will clone the shared material and start using it from now on.

Comment: Well then you are looking for a reference to a material file. I have never done this but i guess you could get the name and find the file by name, but I'm guessing you do not want to do that unless it's a last resort.

Comment: Presumably you considered using the non-cloning `.sharedMaterials` ?

Comment: Yes, I already decided to set new materials by SharedMaterials.

Comment: So what is your remaining problem?

Comment: No problem, I posted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is by design. The solution is to clone a material manually and assign to sharedMaterial array. It doesn't affect other materials.

The next code will clone only second material, do you note you can't assign a new material directly, you must modify array:

```
Material[] materials = line.sharedMaterials;
materials[1] = Instantiate(materials[1]);
line.sharedMaterials = materials;
```